# cmd_ei_api=>maintain_bapi to update kna1 table field (ICMSTAXPAY)

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I have a requirement to update this field `ICMSTAXPAY` in `KNA1` table using my custom report. So, I tried using `cmd_ei_api=>maintain_bapi` to update the table. But once I run the program, that particular field is not updated and I don't get any error messages too.

My logic:

- Read the KNA1 entries.
- Edit the required field to my value.
- Pass mandatory data to HEADER for update.
- Pass my new KNA1 entries to CENTRAL_DATA.

Read data from table:

```
CALL METHOD cmd_ei_api_memory=>get_global_kna1
    EXPORTING
        iv_kunnr    = <lfs_final>-kunnr 
    IMPORTING
        es_kna1_old = ls_old.
```

Change the value of field:

```
ls_old-icmstaxpay = 9.

MOVE-CORRESPONDING ls_old TO ls_customer-central_data-central-data.
```

Assign header data:

```
ls_customer-header-object_instance-kunnr = <lfs_final>-kunnr.
ls_customer-header-object_task  = 'U'.
```

Add all the above to the master data structure:

```
APPEND ls_customer TO lt_customers[].        
ls_master_data-customers = lt_customers[].
```

Pass the data and update to table:

```
cmd_ei_api=>initialize( ).
    
LOOP AT lt_customers INTO ls_customer.
    cmd_ei_api=>lock( iv_kunnr = ls_customer-header-object_instance-kunnr ).
ENDLOOP.
    
" Update Customer with CMD_EI_API
CALL METHOD cmd_ei_api=>maintain_bapi
    EXPORTING
        iv_test_run    = space
        is_master_data = ls_master_data
    IMPORTING
        es_message_defective     = ls_message_defective.
    
IF ls_message_defective IS INITIAL.
    BREAK-POINT.
    COMMIT WORK.
ELSE.
    BREAK-POINT.
ENDIF.
    
LOOP AT lt_customers INTO ls_customer.
    cmd_ei_api=>unlock( iv_kunnr = ls_customer-header-object_instance-kunnr ) .
ENDLOOP.
```

When I debug, I can see that the entry that is being fetched for update is the old entry that is present in the current memory.

Please let me know if i am doing something wrong while passing the value to the table.

Comment: Why not just update via UPDATE or MODIFY? cmd_ei_api is a [customer memory api](https://imgur.com/a/uwLhLev), it does not intended for updating tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need including DATAX with X for all fields that you need change.

DATA: ls_datax TYPE cmds_ei_vmd_central_data_xflag.
ls_datax-icmstaxpay = 'X'.
MOVE ls_datax TO ls_customer-central_data-central-datax.

And thanx for your question, helped me with find this methody :)

Comment: Hey @Rafael . Yes thanks for reminding me on this post. Couple of years ago I was a noob with BAPIs. Later I learnt about the DATA and DATAX structures. 

Though I did not have the time to play around then, hopefully it helps someone in the future.